# TinyMCE4 - anchor link on custom emoji plugin returns null

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am working on a custom Emoji plugin for `TinyMCE4` - when the emoji icon is clicked on the toolbar a big chunk of HTML appears in the plugin window. At the top is a sticky div which contains links to anchors further down the block of `HTML`.

This is the stick div:

```
<div id='thing_to_stick'>
    <a href='#smileyspeople'></a>
    <a href='#animalsnature'></a>
    <a href='#fooddrink'></a>
    <a href='#activity'>⚽</a>
    <a href='#travelplaces'></a>
    <a href='#objects'></a>
    <a href='#symbols'></a>
    <a href='#flags'></a>
</div>
```

Then further down in the `HTML`, there are bits like this, for example:

```
<table style='background:white;' role='list' border='0' class='mce-grid'>
    <tr>
        <td style='color:#000; background: yellow; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;' colspan='5'>
            <span id='smileyspeople'>Smileys & People</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

[This is a working JSFiddle demo of the plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/20140228/ghrzLpcb/).

If you click on an emoji, then it inserts that block of HTML into the TinyMCE content window.

However - it also does that when clicking on an anchor link - so instead of dropping down to e.g. the `#objects` ID block of `HTML`, it inserts this `HTML`:

```
<p><img title="null" src="null" alt="null" width="64" height="64" /></p>
```

[The JS for the plugin is here](https://oracle101.co.uk/assets/includes/tinymce/plugins/test_cat_medium_joypixels_png/plugin.min.js).

I think the reason this is happening is because the JS in the plugin contains the following:

```
onclick: function(b) {
    var c = a.dom.getParent(b.target, "a");
    c && (a.insertContent('<img alt="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-title") + '" title="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-title") + '" src="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-url") + '" width="64" height="64" />'), this.hide())
}
```

Which I think means every hyperlink in the block of `HTML` is treated in the same way...

The trouble I have is that while I can see what is causing this issue, I wondered if there is any way around this, so that the links in the `div#thing_to_stick` are treated as normal links, but all the other links are picked up by the JS code.

I can't use `jQuery` though as I haven't found a way to use it with my Plugin.